# Messages screen in an iOS app

Tags: ios

I've noticed a few iOS apps have a message pane that's just like the native iOS messages screen (colour speech bubbles from both sides).

Twitter and Facebook to name a couple.

Is there any third party plugin or library that offers a framework for building a conversation screen in iOS or have these apps developed custom solutions?

Comment: Try this one: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/acanichat

Comment: Maybe this would help http://alexbarinov.github.com/UIBubbleTableView/

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this recently. Specifically I found this project from Apple to be pretty useful [Apple Multipeeer Group Chat Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html). Here's the full blog post: [Blog post I wrote which contains links to other useful projects](http://www.deluge.co/?q=content/my-quest-make-messaging-app-ios)